# why the code did not work if using master page in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using the code below to create the message box in master page asp.net but it did not work. However, if I use the empty asp.net it can work properly. do i have to set something or put any code.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function Confirm() {
        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("Do you want to save data?"))
        {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    }
</script>
```

this is for aspx.cs

```
{

    string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
    if (confirmValue == "Yes")
    {
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('You clicked YES!')", true);
    }
    else
    {
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('You clicked NO!')", true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Master page requires another ASPX page to run together. Check if you have another ASPX page uses given code in master page.

Comment: i think i have it. cause my master page name masterpage.master. for this function i use updateform.aspx. @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Note that master pages should be used for page template to serve multiple pages with same base layout - use `Request.Form` in ASPX code behind instead. In which line the code doesn't work there?

Comment: what do you mean by code behind? aspx.cs ? owhh when i run the code it will pop pup " do you want to save the data?" . i need to choose okay or close. but when i click either okay or close it will popup the alert "you click no" for both . suppose when i click okay it will show "you click yes".@TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Have you checked `confirmValue` value passed to code behind by `Request.Form` method? If it's not containing `Yes` string, the code for `You clicked NO` message always executed.

Comment: how to check it? sorry if i  keep asking you. @TetsuyaYamamoto